# vsftpd chroot_local_user=YES not acting as a jail

Tags: vsftpd

I have vsftpd installed, and im modifying:
/etc/vsftpd.conf which ive configured as follows:

```
        anonymous_enable=YES
        local_enable=YES
        chroot_local_user=YES
        user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user/
        virtual_use_local_privs=YES
        connect_from_port_20=YES
        listen=YES
        pam_service_name=vsftpd
        tcp_wrappers=YES

    //I added this extra after seeing that simply enabling the chroot_local_user wont work , and created an empty vsftpd.chroot_list, stil doesnt work tho

        chroot_list_enable=YES
        chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
        userlist_enable=YES
        passwd_chroot_enable=YES
```

But my users keep being able to exit their assigned home directory and navigate around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using port 22 for testing instead of ftp port 21
Keep that in mind, thats why it was failing